# Android maven plugin, unable to deploy to device

Tags: android, maven-2, maven-plugin

I've got a simple android project, its building the APK OK however I can't get it to deploy to my device. Currently I have to copy over the APK manually and install it, which is quite annoying.

I've got USB Debugging enabled on a non-maven project, so the actual connection to the device should be ok

When I run `mvn -e android:deploy -Dandroid.device=usb` I get the following output :

```
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 20 16:31:29 GMT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/541M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch>mvn -e android:deploy -Dandroid.device=usb
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Android Plugin - samples
[INFO]    task-segment: [android:deploy] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/admob/android/ads/20101109-ANDROID-3312276cc1406347/ads-20101109-ANDROID-3312276cc14
06347.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.admob.android:ads:pom:20101109-ANDROID-3312276cc1406347' in repository central (http://repo1.ma
ven.org/maven2)
[INFO] [android:deploy {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] C:\development\tools\androidSDK\android-sdk-windows/tools/adb [-d, install, -r, C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbran
ch\target\AndroidSam.apk]
[INFO] 'C:\development\tools\androidSDK\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[INFO] operable program or batch file.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 'C:\development\tools\androidSDK\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operab
le program or batch file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch\target\AndroidSam.apk to device.

Embedded error: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\development\tools\androidSDK\android-sdk-windows\to
ols\adb -d install -r C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch\target\AndroidSam.apk", Result = 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error deploying C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch\target\Andro
idSam.apk to device.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error deploying C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch\target\An
droidSam.apk to device.
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.deployApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:425)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractIntegrationtestMojo.deployBuiltApk(AbstractIntegrationtestMojo.java:101)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:48)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\dev
elopment\tools\androidSDK\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb -d install -r C:\development\projects\AndroidSam_mavenbranch\target\Android
Sam.apk", Result = 1
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:186)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:158)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.deployApk(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:417)
        ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Mar 20 16:31:50 GMT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/555M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is what my POM looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jameselsey</groupId>
    <artifactId>AndroidSam</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Maven Android Plugin - samples</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.admob.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>ads</artifactId>
            <version>20101109-ANDROID-3312276cc1406347</version>
            <!--<scope></scope>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!--  platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                        <platform>8</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <!--  the name of the avd device to use for starting the emulator-->
                        <avd>GoogleAPIs</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    <device>

                    </device>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--  version 2.3 defaults to java 1.5, so no further configuration needed-->
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: On further investigation, it seems that the plugin is trying to call ADB for it to deploy, however the plugin is looking under tools\ and the ADB has been moved to a different location. Trying to work out where I can configure this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice you are using a slightly old version of maven-android-plugin (2.6.0). We added automatic support for the new Android SDK directory layout with `platform-tools/` in version 2.8.1.

Please upgrade to the latest version. See the Changelog for available versions:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog

Thanks,
Hugo

Answer (score 0):

you can install it using adb
adb install {path to apk}